# Push list item in a Nav-var to the right useing flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am makeing a test page for practice and I want to know how to move support to the right

I've tried to put a width of 100% in my Nav-var as I have seen that works normally while including the margin-left:auto;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Doggos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  </head>
<Body>
<div class="Title"> 
    <h1>Hello comrades</h1>
</div>
<nav class="Nav-var">
    <ul>
        <li >About me</li>
        <li>Life</li>
        <li class="Push-Right">Contact me</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</Body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
body
{
background-color: #0E46BB;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.Title
{
background-color:#BB2C0E;
display:flex;

}
.Nav-var
{
display:flex;
background-color: #2C0EBB;
width: 100%;


}
ul
{

display:inline-flex;

}
li
{
list-style: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 0px;


}
.Push-Right
{

margin-left: auto;


}
h1
{
margin: 0px;
}
```

The Only thing needed is to move the About tag to the left and I don't know why it isnt working in this particular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in you css file

```
.Nav-var{
  display:flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```css
.Nav-var{
  display:flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
}


body
{
background-color: #0E46BB;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.Title
{
background-color:#BB2C0E;
display:flex;

}
.Nav-var
{
display:flex;
background-color: #2C0EBB;
width: 100%;


}
ul
{

display:inline-flex;

}
li
{
list-style: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 0px;


}
.Push-Right
{

margin-left: auto;


}
h1
{
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Title"> 
    <h1>Hello comrades</h1>
</div>
<nav class="Nav-var">
    <ul>
        <li >About me</li>
        <li>Life</li>
        <li class="Push-Right">Contact me</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

*edit*

• I kept my ul padding from earlier
• added some horizontal padding to "li", "ul", "h1", and "Title"
• i moved the "About me"-"li" tag to the bottom of your "ul" tag.
• then i gave it a class ".nav-item-align-right"
• in the css i just gave it absolute positioning from the right
  -- you can change the value of the "right" attribute to your liking
• also, i cleaned up a few things in the css that i didn't need

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Doggos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  </head>
<Body>
<div class="Title"> 
    <h1>Hello comrades</h1>
</div>
<nav class="Nav-var">
    <ul>
        <li>Life</li>
        <li>Contact me</li>
        <li class="nav-item-align-right">About me</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</Body>
</html>




body
{
background-color: #0E46BB;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.Title
{
background-color:#BB2C0E;
display:flex;
padding: 0 10px;
}
.Nav-var
{
display:flex;
background-color: #2C0EBB;
width: 100%;
}

ul {
display:inline-flex;
padding: 0 10px;
}

li
{
list-style: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 0 10px;
}

h1
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav-item-align-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chulps/jnyLermu/16/)

Comment: That is great! and that is very usefull, however my problem is I want to move one of the items ,the About tag, to the Right side and not erasing the padding on that side, yet it looks way better without that padding

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position: fixed` and `right: 0` to take Contact Me - li to right. Then you can add your preferred padding.

```css
body
{
background-color: #0E46BB;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.Title
{
background-color:#BB2C0E;
display:flex;

}
.Nav-var
{
display:flex;
background-color: #2C0EBB;
width: 100%;


}
ul
{

display:inline-flex;

}
li
{
list-style: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 0px;


}
.Push-Right
{

padding-right: 25px;
right: 0;
position: fixed;


}
h1
{
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Title"> 
    <h1>Hello comrades</h1>
</div>
<nav class="Nav-var">
    <ul>
        <li >About me</li>
        <li>Life</li>
        <li class="Push-Right">Contact me</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```